# Analyze table for mutual likes between users

Tags: php, mysql

In my database I have a table (likes) that lists items that users have liked.
When visiting a users profile I need to determine how many of those "likes" we have in common.
What's the best way to go about writing a query that will display the mutual likes between users?

```
likes table

 id  |  user  |  item  | activated
-----------------------------------
 1   |  3     |  14    | 1          
 2   |  4     |  14    | 1
```

I need to return **14** in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose should be something like this:

```
select userViewer.item, items.itemName
from likes userViewer,
     likes userProfile,
     items
where userProfile.user = $profileUserId
  and userViewer.user = $userViewer
  and userProfile.item = userViewer.item
  and items.item = userViewer.item
```

where $profileUserId - userId of the profile user and $userViewer - userId of current user

Same query on "join on" form with "items" table, as example:

```
select userViewer.item, items.itemName
from likes userViewer inner join likes userProfile 
on userProfile.user = $profileUserId
  and userViewer.user = $userViewer
  and userProfile.item = userViewer.item
inner join items 
on userViewer.item = items.item
```

Comment: How would I integrate a JOIN to reference the "item" column in another table? It's being a pain in the ass..

Answer (score 1):

I wants to know why you have not used matching caondition in where clause

```
SELECT 
    userViewer.item, items.itemName
  FROM 
     likes AS userViewer 
  INNER JOIN 
    likes as userProfile 
  ON 
    userProfile.item = userViewer.item
  INNER JOIN items 
  ON
    userViewer.item = items.item
  WHERE
    userViewer.user = $userViewer
    AND
    userProfile.user = $profileUserId
```